# Shuffling columns of a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, numpy, permutation, shuffle, numpy-ndarray

How does this line of code `mat[:,permutation]` tell Python to extract the columns of the `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` in the index order in the 1-D `permutation` list?

I know what is happening and how to achieve this. But how does it work

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[7, 8, 0, 4, 6],
                [1, 4, 3, 8, 2],
                [5, 7, 3, 9, 3],
                [5, 8, 3, 7, 3],
                [4, 7, 9, 3, 1]])
print (mat.shape)
print (mat)
print (type(mat))
m = mat.shape[1]
print (m)
permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
print (permutation)

shuf_mat = mat[:,permutation]
print (shuf_mat)

shuf_mat1 = mat[permutation,:]
print (shuf_mat1)

print (mat)
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How does ```permutation``` get all of the column indices of ```mat```? Or how it knows to grab the columns of ```mat``` based on the order of the values in ```mat```?

Comment: It just seems mysterious. How does `mat` know that it has to fetch the columns in the same order as listed in the `permutation` list

Comment: This is straight forward use of `advanced indexing`, that is, indexing with a list or array.  `mat[:, idx]` returns a new array with columns selected by the `idx` array.  `mat[idx,:]` selects rows.